# Multiple threads reading unique records from the same table with Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, concurrency, parallel-processing

We have multiple concurrent threads that simultaneously "claim" unprocessed records from a database table to work on.  In order to ensure no threads end up claiming duplicate records, we use a query that looks something like this.

```
WITH UpdateView AS
(
    SELECT TOP 1 X, Y, Z, Processed
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE Processed = 0
)
UPDATE UpdateView
SET Processed = 1
OUTPUT INSERTED.X, INSERTED.Y, INSERTED.Z, INSERTED.Processed
```

My question is, is there an equivalent way to do something like this via Entity Framework 6.0+ that is comparably performant, or is this not a good use case for EF?

**Update**

So what I'm looking for would be something roughly equivalent to this:

```
IEnumerable<MyTable> results = context.MyTable
    .Where(r => !r.Processed)
    .Take(1) // Up to this point, it effectively builds the UPdateView portion of the original query but thanks to deferred execution, no data is actually retrieved yet.
    .UpdateAndReturn(context, r => r.Processed = true); // Hypothetical extension method that would perform the update and retrieve the updated record(s) as an atomic operation.
```

Unfortunately, I'm unaware of any way via EF to add an update operation to a deffered execution linq query.

Answer (score 1):

The act of reserving a record should be marshaled by a single context on a single thread. For example, given several worker threads that each have their own DbContext you will encounter the situation like you are encountering where each worker could end up querying for Processed = 0 at the same time and get overlaps.

Instead I would look at possibly adding a ProcessorId column to the records and associating an ID to each of your worker threads. Each worker thread would query where ProcessorId = MyProcessorId && Processed == 0. When a worker has no unprocessed records it calls to a marshaled single thread with it's processor ID which looks at ProcessorId IS NULL and Processed == 0 then assigns one or more rows to the Processor ID and returns. Depending on the processing volume you could allocate them one at a time, or batches of 10/50/100 etc.

Update:
You might be able to reserve a record in a thread-safe manner by using a Transaction to lock the table records long enough to pick one and set it's Processed flag. If the record is "flat" with no references etc. to worry about then you could detach it after setting the flag to associate it with a non-tx scoped context where you would be doing the processing etc. without locking the table. Otherwise, simply take the record ID and re-load it if necessary after the blocking Tx is complete.

I.e.

```
UpdateView view = null;
using(var context = new MyContext())
{
    using (var tx = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        view = context.UpdateViews
        .Where(x => !x.IsProcessed)
        .OrderBy(x => x.CreatedDate)
        .FirstOrDefault();
        if (view != null)
        {
            view.IsProcessed = true;
            context.SaveChanges();
            context.Detach(view);
        }
        tx.Commit();
    }
}
if(view == null)
    return;

using(var context = new MyContext())
{
    context.UpdateViews.Attach(view);
    // continue processing...
}
```

You may not need the 2x contexts, just using it outside of the Tx scope with the same context should be fine, but I just put the option up there in case.  If you want to eager-load children or related entities, then I'd keep the reservation read just the record with no eager-loading, set the processed flag and take the ID, then after the Tx closes, load the entity again /w eager loading. This will keep the blocking period between read & commit as short as possible.

Comment: While this sounds like it would work, I think its a bit overkill for my purposes, I'm not looking to do any significant refactoring of my data or adding an additional thread dedicated to assigning records to specific processes.  If I can't replicate the query above in Entity Framework, then I probably won't bother implementing EF for this solution.

Comment: I've added a possible solution if you are looking to just reserve a record. A transaction to find a record, and set it's flag to reserve it might work.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  This is a bit closer to what I was looking for, however as I suspected, performance takes a bit of a hit using this approach vs. the raw SQL query.  My tests show using the transaction to be about 4x slower.

Comment: Yes, quite probably. The limitation is not EF, but rather the multi-threading. The access to the table must be marshalled to avoid a second worker from grabbing the same record before the first worker has finalized reserving it. You can use EF or ADO to execute a read against a view/sproc to reserve a row and return either the ID or all fields, then use the context to load that record, or populate an entity and associate it to the context to continue processing.